# Create an image using the pixels median fom other images

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I have six images and I want to find the median of each pixel and create a new pic from it.
I created a list of my images in this manner:

```
imgs=['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg']
```

and then I wrote a for loop like that:

```
for image in imgs:
```

I've found that there's a function that finds the median using numpy but I don't know how to use it. Also, after finding the median how can I create a picture of all the medians in the correct position of the screen?
How to convert the image into an array?

Comment: You can do it without writing any code on the commandline with **ImageMagick** by the way... `convert im[1-6].jpg -evaluate-sequence median result.jpg`

Comment: but i need to get the median for specific pixel from some pictures and not only one, or maybe I didn't understand your answer

Comment: The result image contains the median for every single pixel. Each pixel in it is the median of all six pixels at that same location.

Comment: but they asked me to do it on python, is it a command line that can be written in python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use opencv to read images

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgs=['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg'] 
np_images = []

for img in imgs:
    image = cv2.imread(img,1)
    if image is None:
        print(img, "doesnot exist")
    else:
        np_images.append(image)
# assuming the dimensions of all images are the same
np_array = np.array(np_images)
median_image = np.median(np_array,axis=0)
cv2.imwrite("median_image.jpg",median_image)
```

Edit:

- `np_images` is an array to store images read by opencv
- `p_value` is an array to store color value of pixel at `(row,col)`
- `np.zeros` is a function that produces zero matrix(matrix whose all 
  values are zeros) of given shape.

To speed up the program.

Comment: thanks fr answering me! I have a problem to run it because median_image is a invalid syntax, do I have to write image with this name ('cause it doesn't exist)? it will be nice if you can explain me what does it mean: np_images = [], p_values = [], np.zeros thanks!

Comment: I succeeded to solve the problem, but when I wrote: cv2.imwrite("median_image.jpg", median_image)
I didn't get anything (the program is running without stop), anyone knows why? I don't think that I have a problem with the syntax 'cause it works before

Comment: I have a problem with the median_image because, I got this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
someone knows to solve it?

Comment: Check that all images ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg']  are found inside current working directory. if not found please remove that name from imgs array.

Comment: all the images in the same directory with this code

Comment: is there any chance that the problem is with the median image?   File "C:\Users\sapir\Desktop\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    median_image  = np.zeros((np_images[0].shape))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: @SapirMelamed I've modified the code so that it shows images that do not exist.

Comment: the program doesn't stop running without displaying any error